# AmCharts v4 - How do i change the color of this tooltop?

Tags: amcharts

In AmCharts v4, is it possible to change the color of the tooltip pointed by the arrow? I just want to change the color of the tooltip and not the guide line.

I am using the JSON approach to build the chart is that's relevant.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution to this.

```
  "chartCursor": {
    "enabled": true,
    "animationDuration": 0,
    "color":"#000000",
    "cursorColor": "#DDEAFB" 
  },
```

The key is the `cursorColor` property inside `chartCursor`. Also, the `color` property will let you change the font color inside the tooltip.